# What is the difference between "@Url.Content" and "@Href"?

Tags: asp.net, css, razor, url-routing, href

It seems that stylesheets can be referenced razoresque either this way:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.duckbilledplatypus.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
```

...or this way:

```
<link href="@Href("~/Content/jquery.duckbilledplatypus.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
```

Is there an advantage to one way over the other?

I noticed that I had this, too:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js")" type="text/javascript" defer ></script>
```

...which is probably bogus (the razoresque-ization of the href that way), as the file on the CDN doesn't need to be razorized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are similar except Url.Content works with applications's virtual directory. 
`@Href` comes from the  System.Web.WebPages library and `@Url.Content` is part of the MVC.

@Url.Content is my favorite.

Comment: It would seem that using @@Url.Content would obviate the need to specify "Content" in the string, then. IOW, if @@Url.Content is tied to your Content folder, shouldn't this work: href="@@Url.Content("/jquery.duckbilledplatypus.css" ? Note: I had to double the at signs because StackOverflow thought I was trying to reply to a cat named Url (Earl?)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using @Href. As I only use Web Pages not MVC. Not because I don't like it but because I don't want to. So for me they are same. It just depends on your work. What ever you want to use.

I would try @Href always.